# Recommended way to distribute an application compiled in MinGW

Tags: windows, mingw, static-linking, software-distribution

I've been wondering which is the best way to distribute an application compiled in MinGW.

For example, if I create a simple helloworld.cpp and compile it under MinGW:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std:: cout << "hello world";
}
```

I get the following dependencies:

- **libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll**
- **libstdc++-6.dll**

Now, if I were to distribute this "helloworld" app, I would have to include not only the binary but also the required dependencies which are part of MinGW.

Is that the recommended way?

Alternatively, I can statically link against those libraries, but I don't think this will be OK from a licensing point of view, right?

Would you recommend distributing the app such as "Git for Windows" does? Which I think they distribute the whole MinGW along with the compiled Git binaries, wrapped in an installer.

Comment: I'd install the last 2 DLLs into the same directory as your .exe (so that they do not get confused if other versions of mingw programs are also on the same PC).  Don't distribute kernel32 , that will lead to a mess.   I personally wouldn't distribute msvcrt either but not sure if there are any 'official' guidelines

Comment: @M.M: `msvcrt.dll` is part of Windows, so it shouldn't be distributed.  (Third-party compilers aren't actually supposed to use it, but there's not much we can do about that.)

Comment: I suspect that Git is a special case, because IIRC it actually uses parts of MinGW, not just the redistributables.  So probably not a good example.  MinGW appears to have special license terms for the two files you list, but GPL licensing is All Greek To Me so I won't comment further.  Perhaps the FSF have a forum or something you could ask at.